# How do I create a custom container view for an iOS App?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am starting out developing an iPad App, and I would like for there to be a toolbar bar at the top that will present different views beneath it as pictured below:
[image: basic layout]

So when each button is pressed, the toolbar should remain in place and different view controller should present its view in that space. I read through Apples ViewController programming guide, and it seems like this is possible, but I just somehow didn't get the actual methods that I needed to get a view controller to display its view inside that bottom rectangle.

Is it reasonable to have a container view which manages the toolbar, and then creates a view controller to display a sub view within that lower rectangle?

EDIT:

I would like to do something along these lines:

```
-(IBAction)hitMapButton{
    MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:mapView];
    [mapView release];
}
```

But I can't figure out how to actually get the view to draw?

Comment: Why can't you use different **views** on different button action, instead of a **viewController**?

Answer (score 0):

Search the Apple documentation with 'Creating a Tab Bar'.  You'll find several documents: creating programmatically, creating with segue, etc.  There are also a number of sample projects that you can view based on that search, for example 'Tabster' (an iPhone app that is a bit dated but will certainly help you - edit the target to be 'iPad').

You can get a working staring point by creating a new Xcode project and selecting 'Tabbed Application'

Note that the UITabBarController puts the tab bar at the bottom - if you are thinking about putting it at the top you should also read the 'User Experience Guidelines'

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to use Apples UITabBarController. I want a custom tab bar on the top. I just need to know the method calls that allow me to instantiate a view controller from within a view controller, then have it draw its view within the context set by container view.

Comment: Okay.  There are numerous examples in the Apple documentation and example code.  Find some example code for UITableViewController and look at the selectRowAtIndex: method - often a view controller is instantiated there (not always, but often).  A common approach is to have all your controllers in the XIB files linked from your container view using IBOutlet - then you don't instantiate them, iOS does and is smart about delaying the instantiation of the controller's view (to save memory).